# React props destructuring returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, destructuring, react-props

I have an issue with destructuring props, it defined when I don't destructure it but it's null when I do it..

```
 const { navigation, book } = this.props; 
 {console.log('book: '+JSON.stringify(book))}
```

It consoles object with volumeInfo object inside it, when I want to access it like this:

```
 const { navigation, book: { volumeInfo: { title, description }} } = this.props; 
 {console.log(title, description)}
```

Then it doesn't, its props2.volumeInfo.title is null
Tried with title && console.log(title) but nothing...

Here is the console log for the first case:

```js
 book: {"kind":"books#volume","id":"__JIDwAAQBAJ","etag":"6y5RWEIbrcY","selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/__JIDwAAQBAJ","volumeInfo":{"title":"Make Me","authors":["Kaye Blue"],"publisher":"Kaye Blue","description":"<p><b><i>They might make a great team ΓÇª if they donΓÇÖt kill each other first.</i></b></p><p>Cree Manning loves everything about being an attorneyΓÇªexcept her colleague, Aaron. He may be an actual prince, but heΓÇÖs also used to coasting through life on his good looks and status. Aaron's hot enough to melt ice, but his arrogance and more than questionable work ethic drive her up a wall.</p><p>His Royal Highness, Aaron Sarda, is third in line to the throneΓÇªwhich means his role in the Kingdom of Medina is mostly ornamental. He hates feeling useless, and working with Cree has taught him that he hates being looked down on even more. Sure, sheΓÇÖs gorgeous, but sheΓÇÖs also rigid, overbearing, and utterly immune to his charm.</
```

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)? It's difficult to say what's wrong from the information currently in your question.

Comment: what is `this.prop`

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
 const { navigation } = this.props; 
 const { title, description } = this.props.book.volumeInfo;
 {console.log(title, description)}
```

Comment: you may console.log(this.state.book.volumeInfo) please so i get a better understand of what you have

Comment: There is log in the post, I can't log `this.props.book.volumeInfo` if I destructure it.

Comment: What im asking you is to run this '{console.log( this.props.book.volumeInfo )}'

Comment: It works this way: `{this.props.book && console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.book.volumeInfo))}`

Answer (score 0):

In the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) , on the left-hand side of the assignment,it define what values to unpack from the sourced variable.

So,in this scenario of assignment ,its not variable declaration for `volumeInfo`.

Thats why  syntaxt error. **Uncaught ReferenceError: volumeInfo is not defined**.

If you want to access `title` via `volumeInfo`  then do like this.

```
var { book:  volumeInfo } = props;
```

or

```
var { book:  {volumeInfo }} = props;
```

In your case,

```
var { book: { volumeInfo: { title, description }} } = props;
```

`title & description` will print value correctly directly but not via `volumeInfo`